# Proof Verification: For $f: A \to B$ and $T \subset B$ show that $f^{-1}(T') = (f^{-1}(T))'$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to know if my proof is correct and if the strategy I use should be used for all questions of this form. Compliments are taken with respect to the set $B$.

My method of proof would be to first show that $f^{-1}(T') \subset (f^{-1}(T))'$ and then show that $ (f^{-1}(T))'\subset f^{-1}(T').$ I will do this for nonempty $T$ and then for $T = \varnothing$.

This seems very long winded and easy to do incorrectly. Is there any better way to doing problems like this one?

Comment: I suppose I left out the possibility that $B = \varnothing$ but I really don't know what it means for a function to map to the empty set.

Comment: If $B=\varnothing$, then since $f$ is a function, it necessarily is the empty function and $A=\varnothing$. From here the rest follows.